# MySQL Groupby Query

Tags: mysql, group-by

[Please see link to get table in better format](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=586&d=1336060648)

In MySQL database, I have two tables ‘VEHICLE’ and ‘VEHICLE_CLASS’ as per below:

```
VEHICLE 
------------------------------------------- 
VEHICLE_ID  | VEHICLE_CLASS_ID  | STATUS 
------------------------------------------- 
vehicle_001 | vehicle_class_001 | 0 
vehicle_002 | vehicle_class_002 | 1 
vehicle_003 | vehicle_class_003 | 2 
vehicle_004 | vehicle_class_001 | 0 
vehicle_005 | vehicle_class_002 | 2 
vehicle_006 | vehicle_class_001 | 0 
vehicle_007 | NULL              | 1 
---------------------------------------------- 


VEHICLE_CLASS 
------------------------------------------ 
VEHICLE_CLASS_ID  | VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME 
----------------------------------------- 
vehicle_class_001 | ABC 
vehicle_class_002 | BCD 
vehicle_class_003 | EFG 
vehicle_class_004 | XYZ 
vehicle_class_005 | PQR 
vehicle_class_006 | STU 
---------------------------------------
```

- There are three statuses 0 = Initiated, 1 = In Progress, 2 = Completed

I need a query to get the result rows as per below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME | COMPLETED_ VEHICLES | NOT_COMPLETED_ VEHICLES 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ABC                |                     |vehicle_001, vehicle_004, vehicle_006 
BCD                | vehicle_005         |vehicle_002 
EFG                | vehicle_003         |
```

- If Status=2 then completed else it is not completed.

Here is the query that I wrote, but it doesn’t give me the correct rows.

```
SELECT 
      veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, 
      vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME, 
      IF(STATUS=2, GROUP_CONCAT(`VEHICLE_ID`),'') COMPLETED_ VEHICLES, 
      IF(STATUS<2,GROUP_CONCAT(`VEHICLE_ID`),'') NOT_COMPLETED_ VEHICLES 
   FROM 
      VEHICLE veh 
         LEFT JOIN VEHICLE_CLASS vehclass 
            on veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID 
   GROUP BY 
      veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID 
   having 
      veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID is not null;
```

Please help me, how can I get result rows. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please correct the formatting to make the post easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## MySQL

```
SELECT 
  vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE veh.STATUS WHEN 2 THEN `VEHICLE_ID` ELSE NULL END) COMPLETED_VEHICLES, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE veh.STATUS WHEN 2 THEN NULL ELSE `VEHICLE_ID` END) NOT_COMPLETED_VEHICLES 
FROM VEHICLE veh 
LEFT JOIN VEHICLE_CLASS vehclass 
  ON veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID 
GROUP BY veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID
HAVING veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID is not null;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59a58/22)

## MSSQL 2008

```
SELECT 
  vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME, 
  STUFF((SELECT CASE v.STATUS WHEN 2 THEN ',' + v.VEHICLE_ID ELSE '' END
          FROM Vehicle v
          WHERE v.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
         , 1, 1, '') as COMPLETED_VEHICLES, 
  STUFF((SELECT CASE v.STATUS WHEN 2 THEN '' ELSE ',' + v.VEHICLE_ID END
          FROM Vehicle v
          WHERE v.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
         , 1, 1, '') as NOT_COMPLETED_VEHICLES
FROM VEHICLE veh 
LEFT JOIN VEHICLE_CLASS vehclass 
  ON veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID 
GROUP BY veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME
HAVING veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID is not null;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59a58/11)

## ORACLE

In order to implement this in oracle, see [this link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) for what to use in place of GROUP_CONCAT

1. Custom user defined aggregate function - most likely your best bet
2. wm_concat - undocumented, unsupported, may exist.
3. listagg - 11g release 2

Comment: Is it possible to convert it in  Oracle9i, DB2 and MSSql.

Please help.

Comment: @user1373028 Most of the query is relatively standard, the hard part will be converting group_concat.

Comment: @user1373028 I added MSSQL implementation, comments on Oracle implementation. DB2 you're on your own, sorry. I have no experience there.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  vechile_class.vechile_class_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(v1.vechile_id) AS COMPLETED_VEHICLES,
  GROUP_CONCAT(v2.vechile_id) AS NOT_COMPLETED_VEHICLES
FROM vechile_class
LEFT JOIN vechile v1 ON 
  v1.vechile_class_id = vechile_class.vechile_class_id AND v1.status = 2
LEFT JOIN vechile v2 ON 
  v2.vechile_class_id = vechile_class.vechile_class_id AND v2.status <> 2
GROUP BY vechile.vechile_class_id
```

Comment: Here is the MySQL query solution for above post:

SELECT vc.vehicle_class_name
, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN v.status = 2 THEN v.vehicle_id END) completed
, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN v.status <> 2 THEN v.vehicle_id END) incomplete
FROM vehicle_class vc
JOIN vehicle v
ON v.vehicle_class_id = vc.vehicle_class_id
GROUP 
BY vc.vehicle_class_id;

I need help converting in Oracle9i, DB2 and MSSql.

Please help.